# Issue in If else condition

Tags: wp-query, loop, pages, advanced-custom-fields, conditional-content

I'm calling my all pages on one pages as a section. Here is my code:

```
<?php $args = array(

            'post_type'     => 'page',
            'orderby'       => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => 50,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'page_as_section', // Calling only those page that set to page as section
                    'value'   => 'Yes'
               ), 
             ),
        ); 

        $onepage = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>

            <?php if ( $onepage->have_posts() ) : while ( $onepage->have_posts() ) : $onepage->the_post(); ?>

                <?php $sectyp = array(
                    'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'section_type', // selecting the section type "Normal" or "Parallax"
                        'value'   => 'Parallax'
                   ), 
                 ),

                ); ?>

                <?php if($sectyp) { ?>

                    <?php if( get_field('select_parallax') ){ ?>

                        <div class="section-dark" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('select_parallax'); ?>');"  data-stellar-background-ratio="0.7">

                    <?php } ?>

                            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                        </div>



                <?php } 

                else{ ?>

                    <div class="section-light">

                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                    </div>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; // end of the loop. ?>
```

The problem I'm facing that only if condition is working and wrapping the page as a section in (div class="section-dark") but the else condition is not working its not wrapping in (div class="section-light"). Where I'm making a mistake.. Please help.. Thanks..

Comment: What is `$sectyp` supposed to do? It looks like the array is always set, so it will always be true

Comment: @czerspalace I have two options in dropdown. "Normal" & "Parallax" . How can I achieve it ? can u explain little bit more? Thanks for answer..

Comment: @cybmeta 'select_parallax' is field name. How can that be more specific? Followed ACF guidlines..

Comment: @cybmeta I just removed the condition for the field "if( get_field('select_parallax') )" now its wrapping in div but in same div(section-dark). not working else condition.. :(

Comment: So the name of the dropdown is `section_type` and you want to check if the value of the dropdown is equal to "Parallax"? If so, is `section_type` saved as post meta?

Comment: @czerspalace . Yes Exactly but its not checking the else condition or what just wrapping all pages in div(section-dark) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the following:

```
<?php $sectyp = array(
                'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'section_type', // selecting the section type "Normal" or "Parallax"
                    'value'   => 'Parallax'
               ), 
       ),
 ); ?>
```

with

```
<?php $sectyp = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'section_type', true); ?>
```

and replace

```
<?php if($sectyp) { ?>
```

with

```
<?php if($sectyp == "Parallax") { ?>
```

Comment: You are genius bro.. Thank you so much.  Solved the problem.. What was that ? why it was not working ??

Comment: @Hussy571 you were never actually retrieving a value for $sectyp, you were just setting that variable equal to an array, and since the array contained values that always returned true